# Why does my covariant derivative look different?

Tags: differential-geometry

> It is known for $f$ a smooth function and vector fields $X$, the covariant derivative obeys product rule
>
> $$\nabla_Y(fX) = (Yf)\nabla_YX+f\nabla_Y X$$

I just did this calculation and i keep getting $\nabla_Y(fX) = X \nabla_Yf +f\nabla_Y X$.

Basically, $\nabla_Y(fx) = (Y(fX^1), \dots, Y(fX^n))$.

Now $Y(fX^1) = <grad(fX^1), Y> = <X^1gradf,Y>+ <fgrad X^1, Y>$.

So putting it back I should get $\nabla_Y(fX) = X \nabla_Yf +f\nabla_Y X$.

But my first term does not match

Comment: You are correct. Your formula is NOT correct.

Comment: So how do I correct the erroneous part?

Comment: Your formula $\nabla_Y(fX) = X \nabla_Yf +f\nabla_Y X$ is the correct one.

Comment: @John, I know, but *why*?

Comment: Don't quite understand your question. To me the formula IS included in the definition of a connection. (I mean, the one that you derived IS the correct one, the one you stated at the beginning is the wrong one)

Comment: @John, oh so you are saying my calculations are right. I got the formula from online notes: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ghomi/LectureNotes/LectureNotes14G.pdf

Comment: Yes, you are correct and the note wrong.

Comment: Thanks and there goes 2 hours of my life...